# Play sound when hyperlink click but remain on same page

Tags: php, html, audio

I know there have been quite a number of questions relating to this already, but I tried following the rest but it doesn't seem to work.

Here's one part my code:

```
<?php
<a href='Recordings/Marvin Gaye Lyrics by Charlie Puth feat. Meghan Trainor.mp3'>Play the music</a>'
?>
```

There's will be lots of hyperlink like this on the same page, the music can be played, but that's after I'm directed to the recording link. How do I stop this?

Thank you for helping in advance!

---

Managed to solve it..
Some things to note: 
1) I am putting @dagon 's Javascript into php's echo. 
2) I used button instead and hide the background of it.

Here's the code:

```
<audio id=\"player\">
  <source src=\"Recordings/Marvin Gaye Lyrics by Charlie Puth feat. Meghan Trainor.mp3\" type=\"audio/mpeg\">
</audio>
<div>
    <button class=\"link\" onclick=\"document.getElementById('player').play()\">Insert text here</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of a href, use the audio tag:

```
<audio controls>
<source src="Recordings/Marvin Gaye Lyrics by Charlie Puth feat. Meghan Trainor.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

version 2, play button only:

```
<audio id="player">
  <source src="Recordings/Marvin Gaye Lyrics by Charlie Puth feat. Meghan Trainor.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<div>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').play()">Play</button>
</div>
```

Comment: how can I not show the player? Because I'm actually doing a English educational website and the audios are  for every paragraph of a reading passage. I don't want to display the player..  @dagon

Comment: @Gwen added a version with a play only button, you could make that a link if you prefered

Comment: Thank you, I made it a link. It doesn't direct me to the link anymore but no music is being played. Sorry for being such a noob. @dagon                          <html> 
<body>
<?php
echo"<audio id='player'>
  <source src='Recordings/Marvin Gaye Lyrics by Charlie Puth feat. Meghan Trainor.mp3' type='audio/mpeg'>
</audio>
<div>
    <a href onclick='document.getElementById('player').play()'>Check</a>
</div>"
?>
</body>

Comment: Yeah. It is correct. It works for the player I have before the clickable links.                                                                                 echo "<center><audio controls>
<source src='Recordings/Marvin Gaye Lyrics by Charlie Puth feat. Meghan Trainor.mp3' type='audio/mpeg'>
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio></center>
<br><br>
<audio id='player'>
 <source src='Recordings/Marvin Gaye Lyrics by Charlie Puth feat. Meghan Trainor.mp3' type='audio/mpeg'>
</audio>
<div>
 <a href onclick='document.getElementById('player').play()'>Check</a>
</div>"   @dagon

Comment: @Gwen you messed up the quote marks breaking the java script

Comment: still don't work.. so sorry <html> 
<body>
<audio id="player">
  <source src="Recordings/Marvin Gaye Lyrics by Charlie Puth feat. Meghan Trainor.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<div>
    <a href onclick="document.getElementById('player').play()">Check</a>
</div>

</body> @dagon

Comment: Am I suppose to put "<script>" "</script>" anywhere. I have never code Javascript before. @dagon

Comment: @Gwen your answer looks just like mine - credit where credit it due?